# Parse Windows log files to pull out usernames and tally pages printed in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, scripting

I am attempting to write a log parser in Perl. I want to output a list of all the users' tally of the number of pages printed.

The logs are exported as a tab delimited text file. There are several columns of information but everything significant is in the last column. The significant portion looks like this:

`Document 34, Microsoft Word - Q5_Springc_2013 owned by USERNAME on COMPUTERHOSTNAME was printed on PRINTER through port PORT.  Size in bytes: 42096. Pages printed: 4. No user action is required.`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
#use strict;

print "Export the \"Printed to...\" logs from Event Viewer for the desired printer as a .txt and place it in the same directory as this script!\n";
print "Enter the text file name: ";
my $infile = <STDIN>;

if ($infile eq "\n"){
    print "No filename entered! Exiting!";
    exit 0;
}
chomp $infile;

print "Reading from file $infile\n";
open INFILE, "<$infile" or die "File does not exist!";

my %report;
while(<INFILE>){

if (/ by (\S+) on .* printed: (\d+)/s) {
    $report{$1} += $2;
}

}

print "$_ $report{$_}\n" for (keys %report);
close INFILE or die $!;
```

I have tried to pull unique names out of the usernames array and tally the prints but I have failed to get any father than this. I have tried to use a hash instead and use a key/value scheme by adding the next value to the old one if the key exists but haven't had any luck. Could anyone help me figure out where to go from here?

I forgot to mention, the output i'm going for is something like this:

```
USER  45  
USER2 12  
USER3 120
```

Comment: I believe the answer is: Yes, probably.

Comment: Edited the code to remove commands that find and concatenate the path to the input file. They were unnecessary as @TLP pointed out.

Comment: You should not fix your code in the question, that makes the question and answer look kind of silly together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way to tally up the sums for each user:

```
my %hash;
while (<>) {
    if (/ by (\S+) on .* printed: (\d+)/s) {
        $hash{$1} += $2;
    }
}
```

The `keys` of the hash are unique, so it will be a list of users.

On a related note:

- If you're opening a file, it doesn't matter if you prepend the current directory name to the file name. Perl understands that if you want to open `file.txt`, it first looks in the current directory.
- `$i = $i + 1` also known as `$i += 1`, or `$i++`
- Use lexical file handles and three argument open: `open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!`
- Your entire program can be replaced by my 6 lines of code, assuming you give a file name as argument.

Comment: Speaking to your other points, thank you for the tips. I have removed the lines that find and concatenate the path with the filename. What are the advantages of using "lexical file handles and three argument open"?

Comment: Marked as answer. I was putting the hash table declaration inside the loop. I moved it out and it works like a charm now. Thank you. I didn't know that the hash tables would automatically not allow duplicate keys (although it makes sense now) and that you could use the `$1` and `$2` scalars in that way.